# R: how to round weights digits in plot.nn()?

Tags: r, neural-network, visualization

I am trying to plot my neural network and I am wondering how can I round the weights to 3 digits.

```
library(neuralnet)
set.seed(0)

x = matrix(rnorm(100, 0, 5), ncol=4)
y = rnorm(25, 100, 20)
data = data.frame(y, x)
nn.model = neuralnet(y~., data, linear.output=T, stepmax = 1e+06)

plot(nn.model)
```

I've tried `mapply(round)` but it didn't work out on lists as `neuralnet` model generates. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
nn.model$weights[[1]] <- lapply(nn.model$weights[[1]], function(x) round(x, 3))
plot(nn.model)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very elegant and efficient :)